# include and require call fails when Double quote is used in php 5.4 easy php dev server

Tags: php, easyphp

I am getting a strange problem with "include" and "require" call in php 5.4. I am running Easy PHP Dev server VC 9 on windows 7 machine.

`include("D:\EasyPHP-14.1VC9\data\localweb\rightcontact\protected\controllers\SiteController.php");`

**//fails**

`include('D:\EasyPHP-14.1VC9\data\localweb\rightcontact\protected\controllers\SiteController.php');`

**//working**

`include("D:/EasyPHP-14.1VC9/data/localweb/rightcontact/protected/controllers/SiteController.php");`

**//works**

`include('D:/EasyPHP-14.1VC9/data/localweb/rightcontact/protected/controllers/SiteController.php');`

**//works**

What might be the reason? Is there anything I need to change in `php.ini` file? Same thing works in `php 5.3` in `Easy php dev server 5.3.8` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quoted strings allow the notation of special characters with backslash sequences. For example a newline is written as `"\n"`. Single quoted strings do not interpret these characters.

See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for details.

The reason why your example works is probably that `\e` is the only valid sequence which is only supported starting with PHP 5.4:

> \e    escape (ESC or 0x1B (27) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.4.0)

Comment: But how come it works in php 5.3 with easy php dev server 5.3.8?

Comment: See updated answer, check the escape sequences in the documentation.

Comment: I think I got the solution. "\r" in the string "\rightcontact" is treated as a special character and thats the problem. Thank you Andy